# Laravel pagination problem one by one pages

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sorry, I have a problem with my laravel pagination Gives me one by one page for example, in my table 16 row I make paginate (10), the pagination gives me in the first page from 1 to 10 and in the second page from 1 to 6 I want the normal pagination from 1 to 10 and from 11 to 16 any help, please

```
 public function allappointmnts(){


  $allapo=DB::table('bookappoitments')->orderBy('times.id')
  ->join('users','bookappoitments.users_id','users.id')
  ->join('times','bookappoitments.times_id','times.id')
  ->join('dates','bookappoitments.Dates_id','dates.id')
  ->paginate(10);

   return view('admin.Managers.allappoinments',compact('allapo'));

}
```

in the blade page:

```
  <div class="text-center">
    {!! $allapo->links(); !!}
  </div>
```

The table :

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>#</th>
                                                <th>Date</th>
                                                <th>Time</th>
                                                <th>Employee</th>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>Email</th>
                                                <th>Company</th>
                                                <th>Phone</th>
                                                <th>Location</th>
                                                <th>Remarks</th>
                                                <th style="text-align: center;">Action</th>


                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>

                                                @foreach($allapo as $Appointments)

                                                <td>{{ $loop->index+1 }}</td> 
                                                <td>{{ $Appointments->Dates }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $Appointments->from_to }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $Appointments->name }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $Appointments->gustname }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $Appointments->gustemail }}</td>
                              <td>{{ $Appointments->gustcompany }}</td>
                              <td>{{ $Appointments->gustphone }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $Appointments->Location }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $Appointments->Remarks }}</td>

                              <td>
                                 <a class="btn btn-success btn-mini deleteRecord " href="{{url('showbymanagment',$Appointments->id)}}">Show</a>

                     </td> 


                                                </tr>

                                                @endforeach
```

Comment: Are you sure that the second page doesn't actually load the 11-16 elements..? There's nothing here to state otherwise.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I can't imagine :)

Comment: Can you show some screenshots of that?

Comment: ok just secound

Comment: https://d.top4top.net/p_1193ag4ze1.png

Comment: https://e.top4top.net/p_1193z8qe72.png

Comment: Can you add your code for the table?

Comment: @rpm192 sure I added the table

Comment: So, it actually show different items. You "just" want the numbering (`{{ $loop->index+1 }}`) different? `dd($allapo)`, it should contain the number of items, which page you are on etc. Do the math. Edit: it should even contain `"from"` and `"to"`.

Comment: @kerbholz No, it makes no different , the number 10 and 6 must be 16 in every page

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#paginator-instance-methods contains all methods for the paginator. Does `{{ $allapo->firstItem() }}` return/show anything? If so, add that to your loop index

Answer (score -3, accepted):

to see the correct number change the line

```
<td>{{ $loop->index+1 }}</td>
```

to:

```
 <td>{{ ($allapo->currentPage() - 1) * $allapo->perPage() + $loop->iteration }} <td>
```

Comment: very nice in looping from 1 to 16 but the total are there any code to give me the total on every page it still gives me in first page 10 and the second 6

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're using the current index of each loop - which will always be within the range of 1-10 of each page (since you have 10 elements per page).

You need to get the current page you're on using

```
$allapo->currentPage()
```

Then get the number of elements per page you got, using

```
$allapo->perPage()
```

Multiply these two, and it will be the base number for your pagination, meaning that its this number you should increment from.

The indexed table should then be

```
{{ $allapo->currentPage() * $allapo->perPage() + $loop->index }}
```

instead of

```
{{ $loop->index+1 }}
```

Then, to fix the heading-numbers (10 and 6 at the top), get the total number of results instead of the count of the page using

```
$allapo->total()
```

See the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination) for more details.

Comment: You'll need to describe what exactly is the problem - what happens, what should happen. We can't read your mind or see what's on your screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php $i = $lists->perPage() * ($lists->currentPage() - 1); ?>
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Employee</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Remarks</th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">Action</th>


          </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr>
@foreach($allapo as $Appointments)
  <td><?php $i++; ?>{{ $i }} </td> 
  <td>{{ $Appointments->Dates }}</td>
  <td>{{ $Appointments->from_to }}</td>
  <td>{{ $Appointments->name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $Appointments->gustname }}</td>
  <td>{{ $Appointments->gustemail }}</td>
  <td>{{ $Appointments->gustcompany }}</td>
  <td>{{ $Appointments->gustphone }}</td>
  <td>{{ $Appointments->Location }}</td>
  <td>{{ $Appointments->Remarks }}</td>
  <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-mini deleteRecord " href=" 
{{url('showbymanagment',$Appointments->id)}}">Show</a></td> 
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thank you but give me an error Undefined variable: i (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\–-prefer-dist - final without delet\resources\views\admin\Managers\allappoinments.blade.php)

Comment: have you pasted this below code before foreach? <?php $i = $lists->perPage() * ($lists->currentPage() - 1); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure, but you will need to write some sort of function to fix this.

Essentially you need to do this:

1. Get the page number (ex: 1)
2. Multiply it by the rows per page (ex: 10)
3. Add the iteration number
4. Subtract the per page number

---

```
function correct_pagination_numbers($cp, $pp, $counter)
{
    $c = (($pp * $cp) + $counter) - $pp;
    return $c;
}
```

Then you can call the function in your view like so:

```
<td>{{ correct_pagination_numbers($allapo->currentPage(), $allapo->perPage(), $loop->index) }}</td>
```

---

It would probably be the best solution to do this in a helper file. If you don't know how to create a helper file and autoload it, you can look [here](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but give me Call to undefined function correct_pagination_numbers() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\–-prefer-dist - final without delet\resources\views\admin\Managers\allappoinments.blade.php)

Comment: Did you change your composer.json file so it autoloads the helper file?

Answer (score 0):

Try ths
@foreach($allapo as $key => $Appointments)

{{ $key + $allapo->firstItem() }}

@endforeach